# Assign ID to cloned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a view were the user can drag and clone and assign IDs to the cloned element and on click of the dropped element I want to assign some values to it so that it can be stored in database for particular element.

It's having 2 div tags from one div tag img tag is dragged and is cloned to another div tag.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", "1.6.3");
        google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.16");
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="dragndrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    .col{
        float:left;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }

    #col1{
        width:200px;
        height:500px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }

    .drag{
        width:100px;
        border:1px solid black;
        height:40px;
        position:relative;
        background-color:red;
        background-image:url(restaurant/8793_532242100147879_270911928_n.jpg);
    }

    #droppable{
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
</head>  

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="col" id="col1">
            <img src="" id="drag1" class="drag">                
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="droppable">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = null;
    //Make element draggable
    $(".drag").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        tolerance: 'fit'
    });

    $("#droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            x = ui.helper.clone();
            x.draggable({
                helper: 'original',
                containment: '#droppable',
                tolerance: 'fit'
            }); 
            var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
            x.appendTo('#droppable');
            ui.helper.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Here I want to assign different IDs to different cloned elements and on click of particular element I want to assign values and store those values to database. I'm new to this so I don't know what to do. And I tried using `.attr` for ID but don't know why it's not working.

Comment: I don't see the setting of id attribute in your code, can you create a fiddle and show us

Comment: I just added a single line of code,but i don't know much..plzz help..